# Server to Client Call Back - PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, callback

I need some solution where server can initiate some call to client without any kind of constant update look up from client, I realize that good docs and gmail has some mechanism where update of cell position and chat message reached to browser even though browser don't running ajax look up request. I try to find solution but not able to find that even don't know is it really possible but I have observe this mechanism in gmail and goodle docs. I am not sure if they have implement socket programming.

Comment: Web sockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by websocket

here is small sample, which you can use.

http://www.websocket.org/echo.html